# How to restrict the datepicker textbox date to future date. it should allow only previous date

Tags: android, validation, datepicker

I want to restrict the Date Picker to set the date above System current date. tell me how to validate datepicker date.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Custom Dialog an show toat on date greater then current date


final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SettingActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_picker_view);
                dialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                final TextView tvTime = (TextView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
                final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog
                        .findViewById`enter code here`(R.id.datePicker1);
                Button set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_time_set);
                Button cancel = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.button_time_cancel);

                datePicker
                        .setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

                Calendar  originalDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                 Calendar previousWeekDay = (Calendar) originalDate.clone();
                  previousWeekDay.add(Calendar.YEAR, -35);
                  previousWeekDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                  previousWeekDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

                  datePicker.init(previousWeekDay.get(Calendar.YEAR), previousWeekDay.get(Calendar.MONTH), previousWeekDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);

                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                final int mDay = calendar
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1;

                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);




                set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                      cal.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

                      if(cal.after(calendar)){
                        Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "DOB not more then current date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          handler.etDOB.setText("");
                      }else{
                             date_selected = String.valueOf(datePicker.getDayOfMonth())+"/"+String.valueOf(datePicker.getMonth()+1)+"/"+String.valueOf(datePicker.getYear());

                          handler.etDOB.setText(datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+AccessRecordForPDF.MONTHS[datePicker.getMonth()+1]+"-"+String.valueOf(datePicker.getYear()));
                          dialog.dismiss();
                      }






                    }
                });
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();


            }
        });


And create dialog.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <!--
         <com.amvrin.PillsScheduler.DrumPicker.DateDrumPicker
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_time_set"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_green"
            android:text="Set"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_time_cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_green"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.pickerdate;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private int mYear;
    private int year1;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    Button pickDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("hello3");
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });

        System.out.println("hello1");
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        updateDisplay();
        year1 = mYear;
        month = mMonth;
        day = mDay;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        DatePickerDialog _date = null;
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay) {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"
                            + mYear + "--" + year);
                    System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"
                            + mMonth + "--" + monthOfYear);
                    System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"
                            + mDay + "--" + dayOfMonth);

                    /*
                     * These lines of commented code used for only setting the
                     * maximum date on Date Picker..
                     * 
                     * if (year > mYear && year) view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth,
                     * mDay);
                     * 
                     * if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear )
                     * view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                     * 
                     * if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear ==
                     * mMonth) view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                     */

                    // these below lines of code used for setting the maximum as
                    // well as minimum dates on Date Picker Dialog..

                    if ((mYear > year)
                            || ((mMonth > monthOfYear) && (mYear == year))
                            || ((mDay > dayOfMonth) && (mYear == year) && (mMonth == monthOfYear))) {
                        view.updateDate(year1, month, day);

                    }

                }
            };

        }
        System.out.println("hello5");
        return _date;
    }

    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            System.out.println("hello6");

            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        System.out.println("hello2");
        mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            System.out.println("hello7");

            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            System.out.println("year=" + year);
            System.out.println("month=" + monthOfYear);
            System.out.println("day=" + dayOfMonth);
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since API level 11 there is a method for that:

1.DatePicker.setMaxDate(long maxDate)

2.If it has to work in previous versions, use this method:

public void init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dialog oncreateDialogue(int id)
{
    Calendar currentDate= Calendar.getInstance();
    final int cyear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int cmonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int cday = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Log.d("", "cyear"+cyear + cmonth + cday);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = null;
    /* if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
    {
       dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate)
            {
               // mTextView.setText(selectedDate + "/" + selectedMonth + 1 + "/" + selectedYear);
                Log.d("", "ondateset"+selectedDate + "/" + selectedMonth + "/" + selectedYear);

            }

        }, cyear, cmonth, cday);
       // Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        dialog.getDatePicker()

        //If you need you can set min date too
    }
    else
    {*/
    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate)
        {
            int lmn=selectedMonth+1;
            sp_dobFlag=true;
            selectedDatepublic=selectedDate + "/"+lmn  + "/"+selectedYear ;
            ed_dob.setText(selectedDatepublic);
            //Log.d("", "ondateset"+selectmnth);
        }
    }, cyear, cmonth , cday)
    {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
        {
            Log.d("", "not>--ondatechange"+cday);
            Log.d("", "not>--ondatechange"+day);

            if (year > cyear) 
            {

                Log.d("", "date >cdate");
                view.updateDate(cyear, cmonth, cday); //update the date picker to selected date
            }

            if(year==cyear)
            {
                if(month > cmonth)
                {
                    view.updateDate(cyear, cmonth, cday);
                }
            }

            if(year==cyear)
            {
                if(month == cmonth)
                {
                    if(day > cday)
                    {
                        view.updateDate(cyear, cmonth, cday);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    };
    // }
    return dialog;

}
```